# Swapped ETH to BTC at myetherwallet.com (via MEW) and still no funds

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, exchanges

about 2 days ago, using myetherwallet.com (via MEW) I swapped some ETH for BTC, with no funds arriving at my BTC wallet, and funds are still missing from my ETH account.

I instigated the swap, some red text on the right of screen popped up for an instance saying "not enough funds" , then a green tab across the bottom of screen stating the transaction was successful, which after about 10 - 20 seconds then turned red and stated that the transaction was cancelled. 
I copied the Transaction details and I have raised a support ticket with myetherwallet.com and bity.com, however have only received a automated email response.

Has any one else had a similar experience or can someone shed some light on resolving this matter???

Comment: Don't use myetherwallet.com. Use Mist. Come on, man!

Comment: Hi there. Can you explain your recommendation for using Mist over MEW? MEW is a very well respected piece of software in the community, and has certain advantages over using Mist, depending on a person's use-case.

Comment: I also had the same issue. hope that the support would reply to my email to them. But 4 days is quite long especially now that I needed my funds for emergency purposes.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: The next day, after posting this msg, bity.com investigated the transaction. To their credit, they were professional and facilitated the transaction and I received the swapped BTC (it took in total 4 days with intervention to receive the swapped funds)